# mod_rewrite remove query and keep string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simple question (I hope).
I have a need to remove the query from the url and rewrite it keeping only the string.

Example:

```
http://example.com/photography/?c=events
```

And the end result should be:

```
http://example.com/photography/events
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
RewriteEngine on

# capture the value of c parameter of the query string (as %1)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)c=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^photography/$ $0%1? [L]
```

?